# How can i assign php define constant value in script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, url, concatenation

This is basically an ajax response I want to assign location from config file I have stored in constant

```
define(BASE_URL, "http://example.net/lc-latest/");
$website =  BASE_URL ;
```

This is my example page code script:

```
if (response["success"] == true) {
    $("#showMessage").html(response['message']);
    location = "/lc-latest/gdpi.php?jobid="+response["id"]

    /* I want to re write this link as `$website` so that if I changed
    the project location it should not disturb.*/

    location = "<?php BASE_URL ?>gdpi.php?jobid="+response["id"] //can i write like this in script of ajax response.?
    window.open(location);
  }
```

Comment: If you changed the projects location couldn't you just change your define statement?

Comment: @RossWilson yes i will change the define for that i am asking how can i give base_url for job page scrpt..?

Comment: `<?php echo BASE_URL ?>` should work

Comment: As long as `job page script` is a php file and not a `.js` file @FrankerZ comment should do the trick.

Comment: @RossWilson Thank you guys it worked can anyone post answer so i can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save the BASE_URL variable in html just like this

```
<body base_url="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>">
```

and then in your ajax response read it using jQuery just like this

```
location = $('body').attr('base_url') + "gdpi.php?jobid="+response["id"]
```